# Происхождение слова "попугай"

Tags: этимология

Каково происхождение слова "попугай"? От слова "пугать" или это заимствованное слово?

Answer (score 5):

Слово *попугай* происходит от ст.-франц. рареgаi или исп. рараgауо, от арабск. babaghā. Так что оно никак не связано с русским *пугать*.